# Android Views in Compose memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple "compose" application that contains bottom navigation and two screens.
The second screen has [custom android view](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#views-in-compose)

```
@Composable
fun ScreenTwo() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            factory = { context ->
                MyCustomView(context)
            },
        )
    }
}

class MyCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView(context, attrs) {
    init {
        text = "MyCustomView"
    }
}
```

By clicking the bottom menu tabs screens detach and recreate again as supposed to be.
But the reference to my custom view remains and is not being erased from memory.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
A [github link](https://github.com/Gark/composeInterop/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/composeandroidview/MainActivity.kt) to the source.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it, you should [report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128&template=1253476) it to compose issue tracker. Looks like a Compose bug, because `finalize` is not getting called too.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198012639